# Refactor code to only have only return statement

Tags: java, algorithm, refactoring

I am trying to refactor this code to have only one return statement but I cannot seem to figure out how. I am searching for a particular node in a tree. Every node in the tree can have children. Any direction would be appreciated thanks

```
private TreeNode getDefaultNode(List list, String supervisingGroupName){

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
        TreeNode tempNode = (TreeNode) list.get(i);
        OSGroup temp = (OSGroup) tempNode.getNodeBusinessObject();

        if (supervisingGroupName.equals(temp.getName())){
            return tempNode;
        }
        else {
            TreeNode node = getDefaultNode(tempNode.getChildren(), supervisingGroupName);
            if (node != null){
                return node;
            }
        }

    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: You can declare `TreeNode node` at the start of the method and set it to `null`, modify it in the `if`  and `else` blocks and return it at the end of the method.

Comment: Can i bother to ask you why ? I think they way you have make it more readable to say the method can return null.

Comment: You can refactor to have one return but it will make the code less readable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can break out of your for loop with the `break` keyword:

```
private TreeNode getDefaultNode(List list, String supervisingGroupName){
    TreeNode node = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
        node = (TreeNode) list.get(i);
        OSGroup temp = (OSGroup) node.getNodeBusinessObject();

        if (supervisingGroupName.equals(temp.getName())){
            break;
        } else {
            node = getDefaultNode(tempNode.getChildren(), supervisingGroupName);
            if (node != null){
                break;
            }
        }

    }

    return node;
}
```

This way you can refactor into a single return statement, allthough this seems no longer clear to me. There was nothing wrong with your code before refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
private TreeNode getDefaultNode(List list, String supervisingGroupName){
TreeNode node = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
        TreeNode tempNode = (TreeNode) list.get(i);
        OSGroup temp = (OSGroup) tempNode.getNodeBusinessObject();
        if (supervisingGroupName.equals(temp.getName())){
            node = tempNode;
            break;
        }else {
            node = getDefaultNode(tempNode.getChildren(), supervisingGroupName);
            if (node != null){
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return node;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not advise a single return; the initial check to see if the names match makes good sense and is clear, and the final null return stands nicely by itself.  I would change one thing about your code to reduce its apparent complexity by eliminating the `else` - after a return, there is no need to put what follows in an else clause, because of course it happens if and only if the return did not happen.  I would also recommend using a typed list so that you can iterate with a "for each" loop instead of a counting loop:

```
private TreeNode getNodeByName(List<TreeNode> nodes, String name) {
    for (TreeNode node: nodes) {
        OSGroup group = (OSGroup) node.getNodeBusinessObject();
        if (name.equals(group.getName())){
            return node;
        }

        TreeNode child = getNodeByName(node.getChildren(), name);
        if (child != null) {
            return child;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

You'll see I also did quite a bit of renaming; I think these names make the code much clearer.